# pyQt5 create pushbutton from dict connect to a function with add value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

i have a problem to connect my pushbutton. I tried different way but i don't arrive to. Sometimes my GUI doesn't show up, stocked in the buffer.
sometimes i have as output Qt.ConnectionType expected, not 'method'
or argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

This script is to download files from the web. In download(self) more of the lines are commented out just to try there is my code.

```
class Ui_Qwid(object):
    def setupUi(self, Qwid):
        Qwid.setObjectName("Qwid")
        Qwid.resize(423, 795)
        Qwid.setWindowTitle("Softs de secours")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Qwid)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 9, 431, 791))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")


        for key,val in les_soft.items():

            self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(key)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.download(key))


    def download(self,key):
        print("on passe par la")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(les_soft[key],key+".exe")


        local_filename = key
        url = les_soft[key]
        # NOTE the stream=True parameter
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
```

thank you for your time

Comment: python2 or python3? show complete code please.

Comment: sorry this is python 3.6
this is all the code
what is missing is 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
#import urllib.request
import requests

and the dict, how is really long, too long to reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect a signal to its slot you should not pass it the function evaluated but only the name of the function. I also recommend that the connection be within the class environment that inherits from QWidget, QMainWindow, etc.

This example I can not reproduce completely, but if I can generalize it, so create a dictionary that simulates your data.

To obtain the desired key we use the object as a source and use the function `text()` to obtain it.

The `sender()` function gets the object that generates the signal, in this case the button you press.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Ui_Qwid(object):
    def setupUi(self, Qwid):
        Qwid.setObjectName("Qwid")
        Qwid.resize(423, 795)
        Qwid.setWindowTitle("Softs de secours")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Qwid)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 9, 431, 791))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Qwid):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.les_soft = {'key1': 'url1', 'key2': 'url2', 'key3': 'url3', 'key4': 'url4',
                         'key5': 'key5', 'key6': 'url6', 'key7': 'url7', 'key8': 'url8'}

        for key, val in self.les_soft.items():
            self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(key)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.download)

    def download(self):
        key = self.sender().text()
        print(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you very much,
for your time, and the answer.
i'm not sure to have understood but i gonna keep trying to

now i gonna try to add threading to this.